# Post-doc vs PhD Prestige

Tags: application, ranking

If a student did their PhD at a mid-tier university and then completed their postdoc at a top 3 university while working with an award winning leader in the field, then when applying to jobs does the prestige of their postdoc subsume that of their PhD?  Or is the PhD university's prestige there forever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One would more likely look at the postdoc's publication record, instead of the name of the university. There is not much "prestige" unless the candidate has strong academics record.

Comment: Supposing that the candidate has a strong record... does this matter at all?

Comment: @CSA Then where the university the candidate come from is unimportant, as long as the degree is genuine.

Comment: I agree but it is easier to build an impressive publication record when tied to a top-rankend university under a award winning leader.

Comment: @Alice Do you want to post your answer?

Comment: @SmallChess Thank you, but no. I just put some quick thoughts in the pool of meaning. I do agree with you ;-) It is the candidate’s record that counts.